# Magento 1.9 End of Life and Paypal, VISA etc?

Tags: magento-1.9.4.0

i have 2 installation of magento 1.9.4 
After the June 30, can we still work with magento 1.9.4? Can we accept payments from Paypal and other Payment getaways?

I know that security patches will not be available but because the cost of migration is big enough i think that it will be great to work with these installations for some months or 1,2 years more.

Does anyone knows about this?